# Airflow and modules

Tags: python, airflow, python-module

Using Airflow, I've a situation in which I have a main application written in python that has some code needed the DAGs I put in Airflow.

- The first, I have freedom on the environment, I can install I want with PIP. This is a standalone app with a `__main__.py`.
- The second get's deployed in Airflow and I have restrictions on the libraries and version I can pull in. Ideally I would like to re-use only a small portion of code from the first (db access, configuration, schemas... etc...).

Now I come from the Java world and an issue like this is solved by creating the appropriate jars... But in python I'd like to know what could be the recommended solution.

My idea would be to have a structure like this:

```
common/
    __init__.py
    lib1.py
    lib2.py
    ...
theApp/ #standalone app
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    app.py  <-- does use common.lib1.py
theOtherApp/ #airflow stuff with DAGs
    __init_.py
    script1.py <-- does use common.lib1.py
```

but I've the following doubts:

- `theApp` works by being called directly like theApp but how do I make it resolve what's in common???
- how do I deploy theOtherApp in airflow together with the dependencies? Do I copy both directories `common` and `theOtherApp`?

Comment: Is there no way you can package the `common` library as a python wheel and require it by both `theApp` and `theOtherApp`? That would be similar to the jar solution you mention. This should be particularly easy if the Airflow / `theOtherApp` are running within a virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

Your second question is YES but not the way you structured it. You will copy both the common and the theApp directory into the theOtherApp coz theOtherApp needs them

Your first question is that you can place common in Lib path of python path or copy common into theApp directory

I have not use Airflow but if It is able to run python I'm sure they will be a python Lib path somewhere that you can include your common then later import in theApp and theOtherApp

Comment: I don't uderstand your solution. I want to avoid bringing around theApp code and it's dependencies, why should I copy it to Airflow?